# Can photons ever be at rest or not?

Tags: photons, speed-of-light

I've read two, what appear to be, contradicting statements in my physics textbook. First it says that all the experimental observations have shown that energy of a photon and its' mass is $0$ when it's at rest. A couple of lines down the page, it says "Photons move at the speed of light, just like EM waves, and are never at rest." and "Photons do not have rest mass or energy". Huh?

Am I missing something?

Comment: The latter are correct: Photons do not have rest mass or rest energy, they move at the speed of light. The first statement might just be a "straw man" argument that the author is setting up just to knock down. It is hard to tell without looking at the actual passage from the textbook in context.

Comment: One guess as to the textbook's first claim is that a photon at rest would have to have zero energy, therefore it would not exist

Comment: Is your textbook by any chance in another language? There may be some translation issues with the terminology of "rest mass".

Comment: @gs That's right, but "rest mass" is indeed used to refer to the mass of a body exclusive of additional mass the body acquires by its motion according to the theory of relativity, as per Merriam-Webster.